# Global state pattern using React Hooks + Context API not working on mobile devices (iOS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uBgda52yEo&t=1126s) on YouTube. Component re-render seems to work perfectly on the desktop (Microsoft Edge) when global state changes, but it doesn't work when I test it on my phone (iPhone 8, tested on both safari and Google Chrome).

Here is the code inside App.js:

```
function App() {
  const contentStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    container: {
      padding: '5px',
      width: '100% !important',
      height: '100% !important',
      margin: 0,
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    chart_container: {
      width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'
    },
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
      height: 'inherit',
    },
    alternative: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    maps: {
      minHeight: '350px',
      maxHeight: '60vh',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    }
  }));
  const classes = contentStyle()
  const { state } = useContext(Context)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar title='MyApp' />
      <Grid container spacing={3} className={classes.container}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper elevation={5} className={classes.paper + ' ' + classes.alternative}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Maps className={classes.maps} elevation={5} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <BridgeCard name={state.bridgeName} address={state.bridgeAddress} image={state.bridgeImage} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <GraphTabs />
          <Paper elevation={5} className={classes.paper + ' ' + classes.alternative}>
            <canvas style={{ width: '100%', height: '60vh' }} id="chart1" />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Here is the context.js:

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

const Context = createContext({})

export default Context
```

Inside index.js

```
const Index = () => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme({ palette, themeName });
  const store = useGlobalState();
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={store}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

Inside useGlobalState.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useGlobalState = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({

    })

    const actions = (action) => {
        const { type, payload } = action;
        switch (type) {
            case 'setState':
                return setState(payload)
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    return { state, actions }
}

export default useGlobalState;
```

Am I missing something or it is something to do with mobile browsers? I did a debug attempt and I got that the component doesn't re-render when the global state changed. Any suggestion?

Comment: Should add what it is that doesn't work and also what library you are using for those components.  Guessing it is material-ui?

Comment: hi @user120242 , thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my post. Yes, I'm using the material-ui.

Comment: Any updates on this ? I am currently experiencing this issue also